# cannot run my java main method

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I cannot run my main method.

when I input: cd /Users/apple/Desktop/java/asd/javacolon/bin/javacolon

then input: java demo

error in terminal occurred: Error: Could not find or load main class demo
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to type `cd /Users/apple/Desktop/java/asd/javacolon/bin/`

and then

```
java javacolon.demo
```

Because the package name is part of the classname